# Cast Varchar to Binary in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: casting, sql-server-2008-r2, binary

For one value I am getting two different values when I am casting `nvarchar` to `binary`.

For the value `A12875` I am getting a result like `0x4131323837350000000000000000000000000000`

I get this when I am using a `select` statement.

If the same statement is executed in a stored procedure I am getting a result like this

```
0x2000410031003200380000000000000000000000
```

I am using the same query

```
select cast('A12875' as binary(20))
```

What is the difference?`

Comment: For one, `A12785` is **not** a `NVARCHAR` literal - `N'ABC12785'` would be....

Answer (score 1):

The difference is character encoding. A character encoding is a way to represent characters as bytes.

The characters you have, and their unicode code points are

```
A    code point 41
1    code point 31
2    code point 32
8    code point 38
7    code point 37
5    code point 35
```

If you use UTF-8 (or Latin-1 or even ASCII) to encode this string you will get, left padded in a field of 20 bytes:

```
41 31 32 38 37 35 00 00 ... 00
```

But there are other character encodings.  It looks like when you run a stored procedure, it is choosing UTF-16LE as the encoding, and that somehow a space character ends up in front.  In UTF-16LE the code point 41 is represented as

```
41 00
```

because it would normally be `0041` but the bytes are reversed.  So you would expect:

```
41 00 31 00 32 00 38 00 37 00 35 00  ... 00 00
```

The space character is code point `20` so it is represented as `20 00`.  I don't know why they put the space up front; it could be a funny way of making a byte order mark, i.e. `2000` for little endian and `0020` for big endian.

At any rate you should look at the SQL Server documentation to see how to use character encodings when characters are converted to bytes.  You know, **whenever** you try to covert characters to bytes, you **must** specify an encoding.  Maybe a default is there, but in general characters->bytes make no sense without an encoding.  In your scenario, the two different environments used two different defaults.

Comment: can you explain by using a detailed example.please me to solve it.

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS this is my database encoding

Comment: Can you simply use VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR?  Or use the N prefix as suggested in the comment to your question so that you truly have a varchar and aren't relying on different systems to either reject the malformed literal or accept it.  It looks like your string can be a simple VARCHAR, though.  Either way.